# SQL Server - Better Solution for join between 2 tables pivoting rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi everyone I am using SQL Server 2016, I have a table called `support_event_log` that looks like this:

```
|    event_nr  |    data     |  
|--------------|-------------|
|     1        |       x     |
|     2        |       x     |
```

And a table called `support_event_log_params` that looks like this:

```
|      event_nr   |   msg_param_nr |  msg_param_value |  
|-----------------|----------------|------------------|
|        1        |        1       |        x         |
|        2        |        1       |        x         |
|        2        |        2       |        y         |
|        2        |        3       |        z         |
```

I want to join both tables by the column `Event_nr` and pivot the column `msg_param_nr` into 3 different columns depending on the number with the value of the column `msg_param_value`, like this:

```
|      event_nr   | msg1 | msg2 | msg3 | data |  
|-----------------|------|------|------|   x  |
|        1        |  x   | null | null |   x  |
|        2        |  x   |  y   |   z  |   x  |
```

I first tried the following query:

```
SELECT A.event_nr 
      ,A.data
      ,CASE WHEN B.msg_param_nr = 1 THEN B.msg_param_value END AS msg1
      ,CASE WHEN B.msg_param_nr = 2 THEN B.msg_param_value END AS msg2
      ,CASE WHEN B.msg_param_nr = 3 THEN B.msg_param_value END AS msg3

FROM support_event_log A LEFT JOIN support_event_log_params B
  on A.event_nr=B.event_nr
```

but I was getting the following result with repeated rows:

```
|      event_nr   | msg1 | msg2 | msg3 | data |  
|-----------------|------|------|------|   x  |
|        1        |  x   | null | null |   x  |
|        2        |  x   | null | null |   x  |
|        2        | null |  y   | null |   x  |
|        2        | null | null |   z  |   x  |
```

Finally after a lot of thinking I got a working solution with the following query:

```
WITH col1 AS (
     SELECT A.event_nr, A.msg_param_value
     FROM support_event_log_params A
     WHERE A.msg_param_nr=1
 )
, col2 AS (
     SELECT A.event_nr, A.msg_param_value
     FROM support_event_log_params A
     WHERE A.msg_param_nr=2
 )
,col3 AS (
     SELECT A.event_nr, A.msg_param_value
     FROM support_event_log_params A
     WHERE A.msg_param_nr=3
 )
SELECT A.event_nr 
      ,A.data
      ,B.msg_param_value as msg1
      ,C.msg_param_value as msg2
      ,D.msg_param_value as msg3
FROM support_event_log A 
  LEFT JOIN col1 B on A.event_nr=B.event_nr
  LEFT JOIN col2 C on A.event_nr=C.event_nr
  LEFT JOIN col3 D on A.event_nr=D.event_nr
```

but it seems very inefficient doing the 3 withs to the same table, is there a better solution to this problem ? I can't seem to find one that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need aggregation on your first query:

```
SELECT el.event_nr, el.data,
       MAX(CASE WHEN elp.msg_param_nr = 1 THEN elp.msg_param_value END) AS msg1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN elp.msg_param_nr = 2 THEN elp.msg_param_value END) AS msg2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN elp.msg_param_nr = 3 THEN elp.msg_param_value END) AS msg3
FROM support_event_log el LEFT JOIN
     support_event_log_params elp
     ON el.event_nr = elp.event_nr
GROUP BY el.event_nr, el.data;
```

Notice that I also changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names, rather than meaningless letters such as `A` and `B`.

Comment: could you have used other than `MAX ()`?  also is it possible to do it with pivot ? or pivot is more inefficient ?

Also thanks for the advice on the naming conventions I'll do it right from now on

Comment: @OmegaKewt . . . `MIN()` would also work.  And you could do this with a pivot, but I find that needlessly complicated.